# Snackbar duration and height

Tags: flutter, height, duration, snackbar

I'm trying to show a snackbar.
After I click on a gesture detector, this snack has two buttons.
The problem is that the snackbar appears for seconds and then disappears.

So I have two questions:

1. How to stop the snackbar from disappearing until the user takes an action and clicks on a button?
2. Also, the snackbar has a height of the whole screen.
   How can I make it have a specific height in the bottom of the screen?

Comment: It's a good idea when troubleshooting to share relevant snippets of your code so we can help you figure out how to solve your issue.

Answer (score 49):

You can use a long `duration`

```
HomeScreen.scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(
    SnackBar(duration: const Duration(minutes: 5), content: Text(message)));
```

See also https://material.io/design/components/snackbars.html#behavior

> *Appearing and disappearing*
>
> Snackbars appear without warning, and don't require user interaction.
>   They automatically disappear from the screen after a minimum of four
>   seconds, and a maximum of ten seconds.

Comment: Thank you for your response.I thought about this, but it will not make it disappear even after the user click on the button, it will remain the whole duration and this is not what i want.

Comment: You can call `hideCurrentSnackBar(...)` on `ScaffoldState` to remove it in `onPressed: ...` of the button https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ScaffoldState/hideCurrentSnackBar.html

Comment: How can i call it on ScaffoldState?

Comment: Use a GlobalKey that you pass to Scaffold.

Answer (score 10):

I wrote a little something about how i solved this https://dev.to/eyewritecode/persisting-flutter-snackbar-until-user-interacts-with-it-2583

You basically have to set a long duration

```dart
duration: Duration(days: 1)
```

And call the following whenever you want to hide it.

```dart
Scaffold.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25946835)

Comment: My bad, I've added more details.

Comment: "Scaffold.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();" has been deprecated. The latest one is "ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();". Thanks

Answer (score -2):

You can change the height of a snackbar by setting a different Max Number of lines (default is 2 usually):

You can do this like this (example with 10 lines):

```
 View snackbarView = snackbar.getView();
            TextView snackTextView = (TextView) snackbarView.findViewById(
            com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text);

            snackTextView.setMaxLines(10);
            snackbar.show();
```

Answer (score -3):

```
final Snackbar snack = Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content),  helpMsg, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
snack.setAction("OK", new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
          // Respond to the click dismiss is automatic with this

           }
});
View view = snack.getView();
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params =(FrameLayout.LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();
params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
view.setLayoutParams(params);
snack.show();
```

Comment: Can you show your code so we can see why you get full page

Comment: Did you carefully read the question tags? There is no `android` or `java` tag