# Flutter SnackBar's height

Tags: flutter, dart

**My Goal**

I want to display the Flutter's *default* SnackBar with a *ListTile* as content.

**The problem**

For some reason, the Snackbar is almost three times higher than I wanted and seems there is no parameter in the Snackbar to set height.

I checked similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52483649/snackbar-duration-and-height), didn't find a working example.

**The SnackBar**

```
void showSuccessSnackBar({BuildContext context, String message}) {
  Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
    SnackBar(
      content: Container(
        child: ListTile(
            leading: _successIcon(),
            dense: true,
            title: Text(
              message,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: HATheme.HOPAUT_PINK,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
              ),
            )),
      ),
      behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white));
}

Widget _successIcon() {
  return Image.asset(
    'assets/icons/success.png',
    // resizing this doesn't help
    height: 30,
    width: 30,
  );
}
```

**The size I want:**

[image]

**The actual size:**

[image]

Comment: please add your code

Comment: Forgot the most important (facepalm), check again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add height to that container and your problem will be fixed

```
 Container(
    height: 10
    child: ListTile(
        leading: _successIcon(),
        dense: true,
        title: Text(
          message,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: HATheme.HOPAUT_PINK,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
          ),
        )
```

Comment: tried a lot of solutions but didn't think about this. Thanks, it works.